# Chrome App webview does not allow access to MessageEvent source in inspector

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

I am using a webview in a Google Chrome app, and when I try to send a message to the webview from the parent page, it come through, but then I can't access the source property to send anything back. I have specified the origin to send to as the parent window origin, and it still comes through to the client, but when I try to inspect it in the client console, it throws an error.

```
webview.addEventListener('contentload', function() {
    webview.contentWindow.postMessage('welcome', window.location.origin);
});
```

And in the webview:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
    console.log(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `event.source.postMessage` was still accessible, I just couldn't inspect it in the console.